# Checkout SVN with SSL on Mac (handshake failed)

Tags: macos, svn, openssl

I'm trying to checkout from a https svn server, but I'm getting a SSL error:

```
SSL handshake failed: SSL error code -1/1/336032856 (https://example.net)
```

I tried everything, but nothing seems to work :(

svn version = 1.6.18
openssl version = 0.9.8r

I also tried to ignore the error with --trust-server-cert, didn't work either.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm having that same error